Redis cluster nodes not accessible from Docker host
I create a redis cluster using the following docker compose file:
services:
  redis1:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis1
    ports:
      - "7001:7001"
    command: [ "redis-server",
                 "--port", "7001",
                 "--cluster-enabled", "yes",
                 "--cluster-config-file", "nodes.conf",
                 "--cluster-node-timeout", "5000",
                 "--appendonly", "yes"
             ]

  redis2:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis2
    ports:
      - "7002:7002"
    command: [ "redis-server",
                 "--port", "7002",
                 "--cluster-enabled", "yes",
                 "--cluster-config-file", "nodes.conf",
                 "--cluster-node-timeout", "5000",
                 "--appendonly", "yes"
             ]

  redis3:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis3
    ports:
      - "7003:7003"
    command: [ "redis-server",
                 "--port", "7003",
                 "--cluster-enabled", "yes",
                 "--cluster-config-file", "nodes.conf",
                 "--cluster-node-timeout", "5000",
                 "--appendonly", "yes"
             ]
  
  cluster-init:
    image: redis:latest
    depends_on:
      - redis1
      - redis2
      - redis3
    entrypoint: >
      /bin/sh -c "
        until redis-cli -h redis1 -p 7001 ping; do sleep 1; done &&
        until redis-cli -h redis2 -p 7002 ping; do sleep 1; done &&
        until redis-cli -h redis3 -p 7003 ping; do sleep 1; done &&
        redis-cli --cluster create redis1:7001 redis2:7002 redis3:7003 --cluster-replicas 0 --cluster-yes
      "

The endpoints redis1:7001, redis2:7002, and redis3:7003 are accessible on the Docker host (e.g. to Redis Insights) as long as they are standalone nodes. After creating a cluster (as done by the cluster-init container), these endpoints cannot be accessed any more.
I am using Docker Desktop version 4.33.0 on Windows 11.
What could be the reason for this behavior? How can the cluster be made accessible to applications running on the Docker host?
